# Sending mail from AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, email-server, sendmail

I was hosting my domain on another server and also using the email of a 3rd party service.  I just moved my domain to AWS and it works well now (DNS propogation etc.)

I also changed the MX Records for the email service.  I am able to send mails but not receive any mails. When I check on a MX lookup service I see my new records when I prefix www (www.abc.com) to the domain but just the domain name (abc.com) it throws up blank results.

Comment: It would help us to know your domain name, but I understand if you can't share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also changed the MX Records for the email service. I am able to send
>   mails but not receive any mails. When I check on a MX lookup service I
>   see my new records when I prefix www (www.abc.com) to the domain but
>   just the domain name (abc.com) it throws up blank results.

If you want to receive email for `domain.com`, the MX records need to be under `domain.com`. Having the MX records on www.domain.com means that your email addresses look like `username@www.domain.com`.

Comment: Many thanks! Makes sense. When i created a hosted zone within AWS, I created it prefixing www.abc.com due to which all my record sets prefix a www.  I have now created a new zone with just abc.com - guess it will take a while for changes to come into effect.  Will report back.

Comment: @Stony You won't need to wait because you're not changing records, you're adding records. What's your domain name?

Comment: @Stony make sure you point your NS records in your old hosted zone against the name servers for your new hosted zone for your new hosted zone to get control.

Comment: @bazze thanks for your help.  I have a newer problem:

while creating a hosted zone, I had initially prefixed www, now I created a new hosted zone without it (abc.com) - the emails are now going through but the domain itself does not load.

As per AWS guidelines, I used the new NS records and updated them. Using www.whatsmydns.net I am able to see the NS records for abc.com but the records don't show when I look up www.abc.com

However, I can access the site using the IP.

Is there some other record I should create on the AWS console?

Comment: @Stony, yes, you need to set up the `www.` subdomain as a Record Set (A record) in your new hosted zone. It should point the same IP as your the Record Set for the root domain already there.